# How install package from source in Mac OS when fortran is needed in R?

Tags: r, macos, fortran, package

I am having problems installing the Package packfor form source in Mac OS X Yosemite in the R software. I know that the package depends on fortran compiler, so I installed the gfortran available in CRAN but it does not affect anything. Bellow I am reproducing the error log.

please if anyone has any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

> install.packages("~/Downloads/packfor_0.0-8.tar", repos =
>   NULL,type="source")
>
> - installing *source* package ‘packfor’ ...
>
> ** libs clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c forward.c -o forward.o forward.c:411:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'dgesvd_' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>   F77_CALL(dgesvd)(&jobu, &jobvt,&size, &size,A, &size,
>   D,U,&size,V,&size,&work1, &lwork,&error);   ^
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R_ext/RS.h:82:22:
>   note: expanded from macro 'F77_CALL'
>   define F77_CALL(x)    x ## _
>                           ^ :8:1: note: expanded from here dgesvd_ ^ forward.c:421:43: warning: data argument not used by
>   format string [-Wformat-extra-args]
>         fprintf(stderr, "error in dinvG: ", error);
>                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R_ext/Error.h:51:15:

> note: expanded from macro 'error'
>   define error Rf_error
>                 ^ 2 warnings generated. clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o packfor.so forward.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib
>   -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation Warning message: In install.packages("~/Downloads/packfor_0.0-8.tar", repos = NULL,  :
>
> installation of package ‘/Users/rafael/Downloads/packfor_0.0-8.tar’
>   had non-zero exit status ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2' ld: library not
>   found for -lquadmath clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [packfor.so] Error 1
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘packfor’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/packfor’
>   >

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, this question's formatting makes it difficult to follow.

Comment: Those errors, with the exception of the missing `libquadmath` library, don't look like comming from Fortran to me. Is `packfor` supposed to work in your OS with the  clang compiler?